# What does being a team player mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, antonyms

Today I was told I would not be hired because I *give the impression that* I'm not a team player.

I shrugged my shoulders and never denied the accusation.

If someone is a team player, what kind of person are they? If someone is not a team player, what kind of person does this make them?

I believe this was a euphemism for me being a cold, emotionally detached--perhaps rude--person. Is this completely nonsensical?

**EDIT**: Yes I know what being a team player *literally* means. I want to know what it infers, or what it could possibly infer. What characteristics are synonymous with people who aren't team players?

Comment: You'd have to ask the person who said it; and they probably couldn't tell you.

Comment: "team player" meaning is easily available online.  Please include your research and then any particular question you may have on the meaning of the expression. (As an aside, IMO, that wasn't a very nice thing to hear someone say to you at an interview!)

Comment: Welcome to ELU, 69110. Since most people prefer being on a team of warm, engaged, polite people, we are more likely to be hired if we can at least **pretend** these traits. Who knows? If we pretend long enough, we might actually become warm, engaged, polite people. At any rate, the answer to this question is not primarily linguistic.

Comment: @KristinaLopez, perhaps the euphemism was a bit more warm and polite than the interviewer's actual determination? It is in the applicant's best interest to receive an honest appraisal, so that they can make adjustments for future endeavors :-)

Comment: @ScotM, maybe so though I would think a blander euphemism might have been easier to deliver, such as "we'll let you know", followed by an  e-mail thanking you for your interest  but that they "went with someone else".

Comment: This employer is someone who I am acquainted with more closely than the average prospective applicant. This wasn't during an interview, this happened today during an off the clock interaction. We had a very honest conversation and I'm happy she let me know...I just don't see why being perceived as not a team player is such a bad thing. I was hoping others could shed light on that.

Comment: There are a slim minority of teams that don't put such a high premium on warmth and emotional engagement, 69110. You may be more comfortable working on such a team, but it seems that your friend does not lead one.  I'm glad you feel good about your friend's "tough love", because trying to work together at that level might have frustrated both of you enough to ruin your friendship.

Comment: This might be better suited to our sister site, [The Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/), but I don't see this as a grammar or usage question.

Comment: Some people perform best in collaboration with others, that would be a 'team player', some people perform best working in relative or absolute isolation.

Answer (score 0):

A team player is someone who collaborates with others, discusses ideas/concepts, **follows the rules**, and doesn't put others at any kind of disadvantage on purpose.

A team player does not work alone.  There is no **I** in **`team`**

A team player makes sure that his/her team succeeds or at least makes a legitimate effort to do so.

Comment: I'd quibble with 'follow the rules'. A team player acts for the good of the team. Sometimes that involves *not* following the rules, especially if the rules were imposed from outside the team.

Comment: "Not a team player" is often used euphemistically to mean someone who won't go along with the prevailing *guppengedanken*, and I use the German deliberately.  As the Depressories poster has it, "There is no "I" in team, but there is in "Kiss My Ass."

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question bro. Cold, emotionally detached, would rather do their work over the broken backs of their co-workers just as soon as help them. Etc etc